# Set up the center of a map with Google Layer as basemap in OpenLayers and GeoExt?

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps, geoext

I looked on similar questions but in vain. The map is working fine but has a center of (0,0) as returned in the Firebug console not (-8, 32) that I want. I did the projection transformation.. Here is my code :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I had to give a look on GeoExt Documentation as well especially the class GeoExt.mapPanel [link here](http://api.geoext.org/1.0/docs/lib/GeoExt/widgets/MapPanel.html). The center of the map and the initial zoom must be specified in there and it worked finally:

> ```
>     (...)map.addLayers([Gmap, institutions, pays]); 
>     var point = new OpenLayers.LonLat(-6, 33); 
>     point.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject());
>     var mapPanel = new GeoExt.MapPanel({
>         region: 'center',
>         height: 550,
>         width: 1000,
>         map: map,
>         zoom: 4,
>         center: point,
>         title: 'Carte'
>     });
> ```

Answer (score 1):

i am curious about that have you tried **setMapObjectCenter** method for solving this problem.

```
setMapObjectCenter

setMapObjectCenter: function (center,
zoom    )
Set the mapObject to the specified center and zoom

Parameters
center  {Object} MapObject LonLat format
zoom    {int} MapObject zoom format
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: I've tried that as well when I looked on the Openlayers Documentation for Google v3 layer :(

Comment: But it seem I didn't manage to use that function properly. Would you plz write how I can use it?

Comment: I've tried this------map.layers[0].setMapObjectCenter = function(center, zoom){center=lonlat; zoom=4;};

Comment: it is already a function. Your method is defining a new function in vain for solving the problem. `map.layers[0].setMapObjectCenter(lonlat, zoom)` should work for you.

Comment: I've been using all this along with GeoExt, as soon as I removed all the GeoExt panels, tree, etc, it worked!